# unique_ptr field with inaccessible object constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

I have following codes, not sure how unique_ptr is initialized.

***a.h***

```
#ifndef EXPERIMENTAL_USERS_ALOUA_CPP_PROTECTED_CTOR_INTIALIZE_A_H_
#define EXPERIMENTAL_USERS_ALOUA_CPP_PROTECTED_CTOR_INTIALIZE_A_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class A {
 public:
  void help() { std::cout << "help ! \n "; }

 protected:
 A() = default;
};

#endif  // EXPERIMENTAL_USERS_ALOUA_CPP_PROTECTED_CTOR_INTIALIZE_A_H_
```

***main.cc***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include "experimental/users/aloua/cpp/protected_ctor_intialize/a.h"
struct B {
  std::unique_ptr<A> a;
  // the default constructor
  // A aa;
};

int main() {
  B b;
  b.a->help();   // this outputs "help !"
}
```

how can the program compile and run without any issue ? 
is it because of `std::unique_ptr<A> a` is zero initialized according to [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) and **no** actual constructor is actually called ?

===========

Tested that the pointer is actually **nullptr**.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` has a default constructor, which initializes it as a null pointer: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr

Comment: if it is a null pointer, how can we do `b.a->help()` function call then ? @UnholySheep

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful and wacky world of Undefined Behaviour. A test to ensure the program is not accessing a null pointer is a unnecessary performance penalty for all programs that do not attempt to access a null pointer, so **no check is made**. It's on you, the programmer, to provide a valid program.

Comment: @javarookie _"if it is a null pointer, how can we do b.a->help() function call then ?"_ You initialize that to a proper instance of `A` before calling? Check `std::make_unique` please. Did you fully understand how class instances are created in c++ at all?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I know how to intialize a unique_ptr, what I don't understand is in my main.cc as shown above, even though I don't intialize or intialized as null as per @UnholySheep, I can still make function call `b.a->help()`.

Comment: As for how can this possibly appear to work, if the method does not use any non-`static` member variables, it's possible that the program doesn't even notice that `this` is invalid.

Comment: @javarookie Well, that's simply called _undefined behavior_, c++ doesn't prevent you from [shooting your leg](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq.html#really-say-that).

Comment: Javarookie, you are confusing syntax and logic. The compiler ensures the program's syntax is correct, the source code can can be translated into executable code, and MAY warn you about any logical errors it spots. `b.a->help();` is syntactically correct and thus compiles. That the logic is wrong is not the compiler's concern.

Comment: @user4581301, it makes sense this can complie given it does not have any syntax error, but the fact it can run and print the expected output is a surprise to me.

Comment: I tried to address that a few comments up. If `help` is something simple like `void help() {cout << " How to use this program ...";}` the invalid `this` parameter is not used can is unlikely to cause misbehaviour. That said, an implementation COULD (because the behaviour is not defined by the C++ Standard) test for null `this` and report an error, but it could also generate code that attempts to launch a nuclear missile at Madagascar. Undefined is undefined. Sometimes it results in something that looks like it works. It is insidious as hell and to be feared.

Comment: [Here is one of my personal favorites](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=73wMnU7xbwE). How may times do you think this presentation worked before Bill Gates got up on stage for that demo?

Comment: @user4581301, just tested it is actully null, thanks for detailed explanation.